# send controls from iOS and android devices over the serial connection

Tags: android, iphone, ios, ipad, serial-port

I am building an app that suppose to control some devices and I would like to send commands serially from the mobile device (iPad or android) over the serial connection to a USB connection on the receiver. Is that possible? Are there any APIs on both platforms? On iPad I guess its a 30pin to USB and on Android whatever the connection is available.

Comment: Commands like? Some things are possible, some aren't.

Comment: Just text based commands that the receiver can interpret.

Comment: Should be possible on Android 2.3 and above. Can't speak for iOS.

Comment: Could you point me out to the APIs?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html